# Oracle.DataAccess.dll version

Tags: .net, oracle11g

I am working on a .NET application that connects to an Oracle 11g database using standalone client DLLs. I'm having some difficulties with DLL versioning. The client DLLs I'm using are the following:

```
ociw32.dll
oci.dll
ocijdbc11.dll
orannzsbb11.dll
oraocci11.dll
oraociicus11.dll
```

My question is, does the Oracle.DataAccess.dll version matter or is it more important to get the version of the listed DLLs correct?

Comment: The whole set of DLL must be consistent, including the .NET ones.

Comment: Is there anyplace to get a few different versions of Oracle.DataAccess.dll without installing all of the ODP.Net versions?

Comment: The only place you can get binaries is really from the Oracle website.